# Как изнутри службы проверить, запущена ли она?

Tags: android, java

Есть служба, внутри которой отслеживается состояние о том, запущена ли она с помощью переменной:

```
private static boolean isDestroyed = false;

@Override public void onCreate() {
    isDestroyed = false;
}

@Override public void onDestroy() {
    isDestroyed = true;
}
```

Практика показывает, что этот метод работает ненадежно, то есть периодически возникают гонки, из-за которых флаг может отражать неверное состояние.

Есть ли более надежный способ?

Comment: предполагается своя isDestroyed для каждой службы ? Тогда почему она static. Насколько я понимаю в таком виде isDestroyed будет одна для всех. Отсюда и проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В результате сделано так:

```
boolean alive = false;
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    alive = name == service.service.getClassName();

    if (alive)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Так избегайти этих гонок.. попробуйте volatile для начала или атомарные переменные.. или даже простую синхронизацию.

**UPD** про бессмысленность *synchronized*

Суть одно из предложенных решений заключается в том, чтобы просто взять и обернуть обращение к переменной isDestroyed в блок synchronized. Однако, на самом деле, это просто ничего не меняет (что этот блок есть, что его нет - нет разницы). Дело в том, что гонки всё равно могут возникать (снаружи блокировки). Гонки при установкечтении флага возникнуть не может, так как boolean всегда влезает в машинное слово. Единственное, что могло бы испортить кровь - это кэш процессора, из-за которого установка флага в значение могло бы оказаться недоступно в других потоках. Однако, такое возможно только на SMP-архитектурах. На данный момент, 99% всех ARM-устройств одноядерные, так что эта проблема не может возникнуть. И для решения её достаточно выставить volatile.

Для того, чтобы избежать гонки, надо либо делать более длинные блокировки, либо использовать атомарные операции. К сожалению, универсального рецепта дать не могу в данном случае, так как не знаю точной задачи. Могу привести упрощённый пример с атомарным операциями, позволяющий избежать ситуации двойного запуска службы.

```
enum ServiceState {
    STOPPED,
    STARTING,
    RUNNING,
    STOPPING
}

private final AtomicReference<ServiceState> currentState = new AtomicReference<ServiceState>(ServiceState.STOPPED);

public void start() {
    if (currentState.compareAndSet(ServiceState.STOPPED, ServiceState.STARTING)) {
        try {
            doStart();
            currentState.set(ServiceState.RUNNING);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // handle error
            currentState.set(ServiceState.STOPPED);
        }
    }
}

public void stop() {
    if (currentState.compareAndSet(ServiceState.RUNNING, ServiceState.STOPPING)) {
        doStop();
        currentState.set(ServiceState.STOPPED);
    }
}
```